# how to relate two list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have two lists and some parameters. With the help of these inputs, I am charging and discharging my battery. In the first list, there are 0s and 1s. 0 means discharge the battery and 1 means charge the battery. In the second list, there are values and with the help of them we can charge the battery. **Battery parameters are:**

```
Max_capacity = 600MW
initial_capacity = 0MW
Duration = 4hours
battery size = 150MW
```

there are actually 8760 values in both the list but I am just showing few

```
signal = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
excess_energy = [0,100,90,160,20,0,0,0,0,0,50,60,70,0]
```

So there are few conditions here:

1. battery can charge only when the signal is 1 and excess_energy is greater than 0.
2. if the excess_energy is greater than 150MW then the battery will charge with 150MW only or if it is less then it can charge with whatever the value in the excess energy.
3. battery can discharge only when the signal is 0 with 150MW at a time fixed.
4. battery cannot discharge below 0 and cannot charge with more than 600MW
   expected output:

   [image]

My approach:

```
battery_size = 150
duration = 4
initial_capacity = 0
max_capacity = 600
ans_charged = []
ans_discharged = []
discharge = 0
days_counter = 0
signal = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]  # Reversed the polarity
excess_energy = [0, 100, 90, 160, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 0]
for decider, ex_energy in zip(signal, excess_energy):
    days_counter += 1  # days counter because every new day all the counters are reset
    if decider == 1 and discharge < duration and max_capacity >= initial_capacity >=0:  # at 0 we charging and at 1 we are discharging
        initial_capacity -= battery_size
        if initial_capacity >= 0:
            ans_charged.append(initial_capacity)
            ans_discharged.append(0)
            discharge += 1
        else:
            ans_charged.append(0)
            ans_discharged.append(0)
            discharge += 1
    elif decider == 1:
        ans_charged.append(0)
        ans_discharged.append(0)
    elif decider == 0 and ex_energy > 0:
        if ex_energy < 150 and max_capacity >= initial_capacity >= 0:
            initial_capacity += ex_energy
            if initial_capacity <= max_capacity:
                ans_discharged.append(initial_capacity)
                ans_charged.append(0)
            else:
                ans_discharged.append(max_capacity)
                ans_charged.append(0)
        else:
            initial_capacity += 150
        if initial_capacity <= max_capacity:
            ans_discharged.append(initial_capacity)
            ans_charged.append(0)
        else:
            ans_discharged.append(max_capacity)
            ans_charged.append(0)
    elif decider == 0:
        ans_discharged.append(0)
        ans_charged.append(0)
        discharge = 0
    if days_counter == 24:
        days_counter = 0
        charge = 0
        discharge = 0
    print(ans_discharged)
    print(ans_charged)
```

my output:

```
Charge = [0, 100, 190, 340, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 100, 0, 0]
Discharge = [0, 0, 0, 0, 190, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I know its a big question but can someone please help with answer because as you can see I am getting 40 and 100 instead of 50 and 110

Comment: Shouldn't there be another discharge at the second-to-last line?

Comment: where? when I am setting the days counter == 24?

Comment: No, I meant in the table, where you go from 110(+60) to 0.

Comment: oh at the second last position discharge becomes zero because every time when the discharge is taking place then I am subtracting 150 from the initial capacity. so 110 -150 will become -40 but I will put 0 because battery's capacity can never be in negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very complicated and it could be simplified:

```
signal = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
excess_energy = [0,100,90,160,20,0,0,0,0,0,50,60,70,0]
charge = []
discharge = []

current = 0
for i, value in enumerate(signal):
    if value == 0 : # Discharging
        current = max(current - 150, 0)
        discharge.append(current)
        charge.append(0)
    else:
        current = current + min(excess_energy[i], 150)
        charge.append(current)
        discharge.append(0)

print(charge)
print(discharge)
```

Comment: this is not giving the expected answer. please see my expected answer.

Comment: [0, 100, 190, 340, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 110, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 190, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
It matches your table

Comment: yeah sorry, I have copied something wrong for verification. But what about those 2 conditions: 1) discharging of the battery can only happen 4 times and 2) there is days counter in my code, which basically count the number of days and set every counter ==0 at every new day.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean. The battery can discharge 4 times in a day? If so where is the date and time information? Also, resetting counter wont help because discharge 4 times within 24 hours need not reset at midnight. Within any window of 24 hours it can discharge 4 times.

Comment: Is the signal frequency 1 per hour?

Comment: yes, and yeah I added my further requirement in code on my own. Thanks!